# DispatcherTimer only fires once

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have something like

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded
    Timer1 = New DispatcherTimer
    Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)
    AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf TickMe
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TickMe()
//calls a function here
End Sub
```

It only calls once the function and doesn't call it subsequently. How do i make it calls every 2 seconds?

Comment: What does the function do inside `TickMe`? Is your whole UI hanging? Have you tried doing something simple like `Console.WriteLine` in `TickMe`?

Comment: it call another function to change text label

Comment: So what makes you think it's only being called once? Did you set a breakpoint or are you merely observing the label?

Comment: obversing the label yes, it suppose to increase by 1 every 2 seconds, from 0 to 1 yes, then it stops there

Comment: My point is that the `TickMe` function probably *is* being called every two seconds, but you have flawed logic updating the label. Check your premise!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you've put in the event handler, but this works fine for me.
Try putting a call to `MessageBox.Show("hello world")` in the handler, and you'll see the DispatcherTimer will keep firing until you call `Stop()`.